# How to validate manually at client in Asp.net MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to validate form when click client button out of form, i tryed some method but all failed,help please?
source code:

```
@model MvcTest.Models.Movie
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    Html.EnableClientValidation(true);
}
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
@using (Html.BeginForm("TestValidate", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "tf" }))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Title)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Title)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Title)
}
<a onclick="test(event)" href="#">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test() {
          //How to write here?
    }
</script>

namespace MvcTest.Models
{
    public class Movie
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Error Message Test,I want you")]
        public string Title { get; set; }    
    }
    public class MovieDBContext : DbContext { 
        public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

---

I invoked valid but ,it always warning the object form don't support this methord "validate()"

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("#myform").validate();
        $("test").click(function() {
          alert("Valid: " + $("#myform").valid());
          return false;
        });
  });
```

I have import js like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/validate/lib/jquery.delegate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

or these:

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I have solved this problom, because I use Telerik framework in my project ,and that cause this problem. So i want Which UI Component is best for MVC project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the [`valid` method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid).